# Sum and Row functions - Excel

Tags: excel, sum, row

I m trying to use `SUM()` & `ROW()` together without any luck. I want to sum up the values starting from `K1` up to the current line, but i getting an error.

Formula:

`=SUM(K1&":K"&ROW(K1))`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("$K$1:K"&ROW(K1)))`

Thanks for you time!

Comment: If you are going to be entering this formula in a range of say, ``L1:Ln`, there's no need for `INDIRECT` at all.  Just use, eg: `L1: =SUM($K$1:K1)` and fill down.